Incompressible fluid accelerating in a completely sealed container
Assume a sealed container with a fluid that doesn't compress. And let's say that the container is given an acceleration $a$ towards the right.

Now, if the container wasn't sealed, the liquid would rise up on the left, and there would be a pressure difference of $pla$, where $p$ is the density of the fluid, and $l$ is the distance of the two points under consideration. And this difference in pressure is compensated by the rise in the height of the liquid on the left.

But, this time, the container is sealed, the liquid cannot rise, so how will the the pressure difference accumulate. Will there be a pressure difference? How to use mechanics to identify that.

Is this an ill-posed question?

The effects of acceleration to the right can be analyzed in a reference frame that accelerates with the container. Here, we can think of a pseudo force that acts in the opposite direction as the acceleration. This is now a simpler picture: in the unsealed case, the liquid moves up on one side because it is starting to “spill” according to this new “force”, analogous to if you had just tilted the container in an inertial reference frame (note I say analogous, not completely equivalent).
So then, the same is true of the sealed container. The pressure in the fluid will be equivalent to that of one placed in a different gravitational field whose magnitude and orientation are the vector sum of that of the Earth’s and that arising from the pseudoforce generated by acceleration.

You can easily solve your problem, up to an additive constant providing the absolute value of pressure in one point, and thus in the whole domain, otherwise unknown, using momentum equation of continuum mechanics for stationary flows, namely
$$\overline{\rho} \mathbf{a} = \overline{\rho} \mathbf{g} - \nabla P \ , $$
in an inertial frame or
$$\mathbf{0} = \overline{\rho} \mathbf{\tilde{g}} - \nabla P \ , $$
being $\mathbf{\tilde{g}} = \mathbf{g} - \mathbf{a}= \tilde{g} \, \hat{\mathbf{z}}$ the acceleration field in the fluid, as perceived in the accelerating frame. If the acceleration field is uniform, the solution of this equation reads
$$P(z) - P(z_0) = \overline{\rho} \tilde{g} (z - z_0) \ .$$
From the latter equation you can easily find the relative pressure in two points of the fluid, while you need a "boundary condition" $P(z_0) = P_0$ to find absolute value of pressure.
